# Add options to Visual Swatch by Rest API

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api

Can options ​​be entered into a Visual Swatch attribute by API Rest?

Comment: Is it a configurable product, and the product is exists already?

Comment: Only the attribute. I use the following url rest path: /V1/products/attributes via POST.